# How to do prediction on survival data, using Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, prediction, survival-analysis

I should make prediction on survival data, using the random Forest method. My question is: should I follow the same approach as in logistic regression? taking into account only the status variable or whether I should take into account the delay to the event?  Are there any specific R functions for survival analysis other than `randomForest`? Or could I use this function for survival analysis as well? I've seen a function called `ranger()` that seems to do random forest on survival data, but I haven't understood much of it.

Comment: Definitely use survival times and censoring times. There are, of course, the "classical" methods supported by the "recommended" package named: "survival". There's also fairly well-known "randomForestSRC". The `ranger` package touts its abilities to handle sparse predictors. That would definitely be an important advantage if your data fit that description.